# Tensorflow Model, Random Forest AUC - How to calculate using Session?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, random-forest

Trying to figure out how to calculate AUC in Random Forest Tensorflow when using Session training.

Tried many approaches like the ones mentioned here:

- [Tensorflow 1.4 tf.metrics.auc for AUC calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174323/tensorflow-1-4-tf-metrics-auc-for-auc-calculation)
- [Can't seem to get Tensorflow's tf.metrics.auc working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632656/cant-seem-to-get-tensorflows-tf-metrics-auc-working)
- [How to calculate auc in tensorflow in an easy way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408810/how-to-calculate-auc-in-tensorflow-in-an-easy-way)

I think that I cannot do follow these patterns above using the code seen here:

```py
# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(input_x, input_y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

data1 = data.iloc[:,:].values


# Parameters
num_steps = 50 # Total steps to train
num_classes = 2 
num_features = 14
num_trees = 10 
max_nodes = 1000 

# Input and Target placeholders 
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_features])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[None])


# Random Forest Parameters
hparams = tensor_forest.ForestHParams(num_classes=num_classes, num_features=num_features, num_trees=num_trees, max_nodes=max_nodes).fill()

# Build the Random Forest
forest_graph = tensor_forest.RandomForestGraphs(hparams)
train_op = forest_graph.training_graph(X, Y)
loss_op = forest_graph.training_loss(X, Y)
infer_op, _, _ = forest_graph.inference_graph(X)

### ACCURACY DEFINITION
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(infer_op, 1), tf.cast(Y, tf.int64))
accuracy_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))


### AUC DEFINITION
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
HELP HERE ? 


### SESSION DEFINITION
init_vars = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), resources.initialize_resources(resources.shared_resources()))

sess = tf.Session()

# Training here
for i in range(1, num_steps + 1):
    _, l = sess.run([train_op, loss_op], feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: y_train})
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())


    if i % 50 == 0 or i == 1:

        acc = sess.run(accuracy_op, feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: y_train})
        HELP HERE TO MAKE AUC AVAILABLE TOO?        

        print('Step %i, Loss: %f, Acc: %f' % (i, l, acc))


# EVALUATION
print("Test Accuracy:", sess.run(accuracy_op, feed_dict={X: X_test, Y: y_test}))

HELP HERE TO PRINT AUC?
```

Can anyone help me to understand how to include AUC calc here?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
predictions=pd.DataFrame(model.predict_proba(X_test),columns=model.classes_)
roc_score = roc_auc_score((real_test_class == 'True').astype(float), predictions['True'])
```

Where real_test_class is the vector holding your real class, and predictions['True'] is the column in the predictions dataframe which holds the ***probabilities*** of each sample being 'True'

Comment: Sorry if I'm going to ask a noob question :)

Shouldn't the real_test_class be a y_train or y_test? Looking at the code above, can you please guide me to where I should introduce this code?

Comment: real_test_class is your y_test. put the roc_score calculations after you use predict_proba, to predict the probabilities of your true class. Don't forget to import the roc_score_auc from sklearn. I added the predict_proba to the code. Note that tensorflow can use the same roc_auc_score function, just give it the correct probabilities.